# DateTime object generates incorrect result

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to create start and end dates using DateTime objects in PHP to perform some calculations.  I currently generate the dates as follows:

```
$end = new DateTime(date("Y-m-t 23:59:59", strtotime("last month")));
$start = new DateTime(date("Y-m-1 00:00:00", strtotime("-6 months", $end->getTimestamp())));
```

What this will do is give me an end date of the final day of the previous month and a start date of the first day of the month six months prior to the end date.  I've run some tests and this gives me the desired results of `2015-7-1` and `2015-12-31`.  However, I've tried specifying different dates for the end date and receive erroneous results.  Two particular examples are below:

```
$end = new DateTime(date("Y-m-t 23:59:59", strtotime("now")));
$start = new DateTime(date("Y-m-1 00:00:00", strtotime("-6 months", $end->getTimestamp())));

$end = new DateTime(date("Y-2-t 23:59:59"));
$start = new DateTime(date("Y-m-1 00:00:00", strtotime("-6 months", $end->getTimestamp())));
```

The first gives me a start date of `2015-7-1` yet again but correctly produces `2016-1-31` as the end date, and the second gives me a start date of `2015-9-1` and an end date of `2016-3-2`.  What exactly am I doing wrong?  I want these dates to be generated automatically, as per the first code segment.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix old and new functionality. You can simply use the interval method, like this:

```
$dt = new DateTime; // now
$dt->modify('+6 months'); // add 6 months to 'now'
echo $dt->format('Y-m-t');

$dt->modify('-7 hours');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-t');
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Comment: I can't just rely on a single object.  I need the second mostly for the sake of performing some calculations (specifically the number of days between the two, which I know how to obtain using the `diff` method).  How can I create the second object using this style you've shown?